# Enabling an azure metric alert V2

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, monitor, azure-alerts

i am working on azure to monitor appservices and while a Continous deployments i am trying to build an automation task to disable/enable alert during deployments

For disabling alerts it is working

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"  -Name "<alert name>" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule
```

For enabling the alerts after the deployments

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"  -Name "<alert name>" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -TargetResourceRegion "westeurope"
```

I get the following error:

```
Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2: Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Alert update failed. Updating from StaticThresholdCriteria and odata.type SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria to StaticThresholdCriteria and odata.type MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria is not supported. Activity ID: ec818831-0516-44a7-92ff-cbddaa82b634., Code: BadRequest, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: BadRequest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not change the region by passing `-TargetResourceRegion` param while enabling. `Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2` is trying add a new rule thinking that it's a new rule and failing because of the shown error message (`Updating from StaticThresholdCriteria and odata.type SingleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria to StaticThresholdCriteria and odata.type MultipleResourceMultipleMetricCriteria is not supported`). So just enable by without passing any other params like below.

```
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName "<resource group name>"  -Name "<alert name>" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2
```